# DLookup Function in Access returns Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, ms-access, dlookup

I'm trying to use the DLookup function and it keeps giving me a type mismatch error. See code below:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[CheckedOutTo]", "tbl_Transaction", "[CheckedInDate]" = Null And "AssetID = " & Forms!frm_NewTransaction!SN))
```

CheckedOutTo is Short Text, CheckedInDate is a date, and AssetID is a number. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there's an error in my syntax somewhere. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include the criteria values as part of the string supplied to `DLookup`, i.e.:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("CheckedOutTo", "tbl_Transaction", "CheckedInDate is null and AssetID = Forms!frm_NewTransaction!SN"))
```

Comment: as AssetID is a number, your original code in the dlookup looks correct, so in combination with @lee mac answer, you will need your dlookup to read like this so that you pass the AssetID itself, not the control name. 
If IsNull(DLookup("CheckedOutTo", "tbl_Transaction", "CheckedInDate is null and AssetID = " & Forms!frm_NewTransaction!SN))

Comment: @JennyW Did you test my suggestion? The form reference will be evaluated without the need for concatenation, which also avoids the need to handle varying data types.

Comment: I’m so sorry, I hadn’t- though I just have! i’ve never seen that before, i’m pretty new to VBA and have only used concatenation and handling the data types before, and read lots of questions and answers on here about how to handle the different data types. I’ve not seen anyone suggest doing it with the form reference like this before. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it this way:

```vb
If IsNull(DLookup("CheckedOutTo", "tbl_Transaction", "CheckedInDate is Null and AssetID = " & Forms!frm_NewTransaction!SN)) Then ...
```